# My apps Splashscreen fails on android 4.0 Ice Cream Sandwich

Tags: android, crash, splash-screen, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I currently have a simple app in the market, now I tried installing it on an Android 4.0 device.
But it fails after my Splashscreen closes. I send a rapport and got this as feedback:

```
Crash
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
Thread.stop()
```

and

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at java.lang.Thread.stop(Thread.java:1076)
at java.lang.Thread.stop(Thread.java:1063)
at com.lars.PSVWebView.SplashScreen$1.run(SplashScreen.java:35)
```

this is the code, since last edit:

```
package com.lars.DrinkRecOrder;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;

public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(SplashScreen.this, DrinkRecOrderActivity.class);
                }{
                /* start the activity */
                startActivity(new Intent("com.lars.DrinkRecorder.splashscreen.DrinkRecorderActivity"));
            }
        }, 500);

    }
}
```

So this is my new code... no errors, but doesn't work either, my app crashes at startup.
By the way... same splashscreen code, different app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the answer!

```
package com.lars.DrinkRecOrder;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;

public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                /* start the activity */
                startActivity(new Intent("com.lars.DrinkRecOrder.splashscreen.DrinkRecOrderActivity"));
            }
        }, 5000);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this method:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(SplashScreen.this, NextActivity.class);
                }
                /* start the activity */
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }, SPLASH_SCREEN_TIME_IN_MILLISECONDS);
```

I think it's far better and elegant than `Thread.sleep()`

Comment: I'm not sure what parts of my code I should replace, I made this according to a tutorial

Comment: You could copy the code I wrote above and paste into your onCreate() method.. also you have to change the NextActivity.class with your desired activity class(the one you want to be oppened after the splash screen) and set a number of milliseconds instead of SPLASH_SCREEN_TIME_IN_MILLISECONDS variable

Comment: I edited the last part to show you what I did, but I still get errors, I'm sorry if I'm bothering you..

Comment: try to change the startActivity() call with yours.. startActivity(new Intent("com.lars.PSVWebView.splashscreen.PsvWebViewActivity"));

Answer (score 1):

[Read the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#stop%28java.lang.Throwable%29) on `Thread.stop()`.

> This method is deprecated.
>   because stopping a thread in this manner is unsafe and can leave your application and the VM in an unpredictable state.
>
> Throws `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Comment: Also there's absolutely no reason to stop it at that point. Your Thread stops without explicitly stopping it as execution flows away from run() method.